# Transform recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, transformation

Is it possible to transform following recurrence relation $a_n=4a_{n-2}-a_{n-4}$, $a_0=1$, $a_1=0$, $a_2=3$, $a_3=0$ so that it will have nonnegative coefficients? Number of terms, of course, can be be larger.

EDIT: Moving terms to left side is not that I actually wanted.
I need that there is only one element on the left, with largest index.

For example: sequence $a_n=1-a_{n-1}$, $a_0=1$, $a_1=0$ is the same as $a_n=a_{n-2}$, $a_0=1$, $a_1=0$, but second one has only nonnegative coefficients.

Comment: No.${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: But how it is possible for given example and not possible for one I need?

Comment: What do you want this for?

Comment: That sequence describes number of ways domino tiles 3xn rectangle. I will be able to prove that formula is correct if there wasn't minus sign.

Comment: @Somnium, that is a quite different recurrence... you can' just go and change a coefficient like that and hope to get the same sequence.